# ERROR in ./src/firebase.config.js 6:0-53 Module not found: Error: Package path ./getFirestore is not exported from package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I'm following a tutorial and I'm not sure what the problem is I keep getting an error when I try to `import { db } from '../firebase.config'`.

I've tried everything and looked at the tutorials code in git they're the same so I think the problem is new.

This is the `firebase.config.js` file and the `SignUp.jsx` file where I tried to import `db`.

```
    // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
    import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
    import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
    import { getFirestore} from 'firebase/getFirestore';
    // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
    const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: ****,
      authDomain:****
      projectId: ****",
      storageBucket: ****,
      messagingSenderId: ****,
      appId: ****,
      measurementId: ****
    };

    // Initialize Firebase
    initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const analytics = getFirestore();
    const db = getFirestore()
    export default db;



    import React from 'react'
    import { useRef, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
    import {Link, useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom'
    import {faCheck, faTimes, faInForCircle } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
    import { fontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
    import { 
      getAuth, 
      createUserWithEmailAndPassword, 
      updateProfile 
    } from 'firebase/auth';
    import { db } from '../firebase.config';
```

Comment: When you export `db` in your case using `default` keyword - you need to import it with `import db from "...."`. If you export without `default` - then import will be `import { db } from "...."`

Answer (score 0):

You are exporting the DB as default, to make it work export this way:

firebase.config

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
import { getFirestore} from 'firebase/getFirestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: ****,
  authDomain:****
  projectId: ****,
  storageBucket: ****,
  messagingSenderId: ****,
  appId: ****,
  measurementId: ****
};

// Initialize Firebase
initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getFirestore();
const db = getFirestore()

// THIS WAY
export {app, db, analytics};
```

Then on your file you can import this way

```
// HERE IM SHOWING MORE THAN JUST IMPORT THE DB, BUT YOU CAN IMPORT JUST WHAT YOU WANT
import {app, db, analytics} from "./firebase.config"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem.

Its `import {getFirestore} from "firebase/firestore";` and not `import { getFirestore} from 'firebase/getFirestore';`.